# Canvas width must be equal to window width but height should be equal to image's natural height

Tags: canvas

On page load, canvas with image must be equal to browser's width but height of canvas is equal to image's natural height.kindly visit this https://jsfiddle.net/amitv1093/8yo3rLh1/

I'm creating image viewer with Area selection feature but the problem is loaded canvas has width and height same as image's natural width and height. because of this canvas look like zoom In mode. I want that canvas and its perfectly fit image should be equal to browser width(no horizontal scroll, vertical scroll is fine) .

if I want to zoom canvas and that time horizontal scroll will come then that will be fine because without scroll it is impossible to see invisible area.
    That will I do easily, this is just a basic idea about what I'm going to do.

I visited many links and found many solutions but no one worked for me.

**note that I don't want stretched image inside canvas.**

please help me. Thanks in advance.

==html==

```
<canvas ></canvas>
```

==Js==

```
var canvas = $('canvas');
            var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
            var mousedown = false;
            var imageObj = new Image(); 

            imageObj.onload = function() {


              $(canvas).attr({
                width : this.width,
                height: this.height
              });
              context.drawImage(imageObj,0,0); 
            }; 
            imageObj.src = 'https://www.livecareer.com/images/uploaded/resume-example-home/web-developer-resume-example-emphasis-2-expanded-2.png'; 

            var clicks = [];

            function drawRectangle(){
              context.beginPath();
              context.rect(clicks[0].x, clicks[0].y, clicks[1].x-clicks[0].x, clicks[1].y-clicks[0].y);
              context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,235,59,0.5)';
              context.fill();
              context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
              context.lineWidth = 1;
              context.stroke();
            };

            function drawPoints(){
              context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26"; 
              //context.lineJoin = "round"; 
              context.lineWidth = 5; 

              for(var i=0; i < clicks.length; i++){ 
                context.beginPath(); 
                context.arc(clicks[i].x, clicks[i].y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false); 
                context.fillStyle = '#ffffff'; 
                context.fill(); 
                context.lineWidth = 5; 
                context.stroke(); 
              }
            };

            function redraw(){ 
              canvas.width = canvas.width; // Clears the canvas 
              context.drawImage(imageObj,0,0); 

              drawRectangle();
              drawPoints();
            };

            canvas
              .mousedown(function (e) {
                clicks[0] = {
                  x: e.offsetX,
                  y: e.offsetY
                };
                mousedown = true;
              })
              .mousemove(function (e) {
                if (mousedown) {
                  clicks[1] = {
                    x: e.offsetX,
                    y: e.offsetY
                  };
                  redraw();
                }
              })
              .mouseup(function (e) {
                mousedown = false;
                clicks[1] = {
                  x: e.offsetX,
                  y: e.offsetY
                };
              })
              .mouseleave(function (event) {
                mousedown = false;
              });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your canvas width using css, then the image will load into that size, rather than its natural width/height.

In main.css (or whatever css file you want)

```
canvas {
    width: 80%; //can be 80vw, 500px, whatever you want
}
```

Note that depending on how your click to draw rectangle is set up, you may have to tweak some things to get the correct scale for the rectangle you draw.

---

I've edited you code and put it here: https://jsfiddle.net/odnkaha4/3/

I've changed your rectangle drawing code slightly so that it works with whatever canvas size you want. You can set the canvas size in `<canvas width=800><canvas>` or in the css style sheet like above.

**However**, if you do set a width in the css style sheet, this will override whatever you have written directly on the canvas object.

Comment: @minididds, Help me for this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926231/on-canvas-allow-image-area-highlighting-on-zoomin-zoomout-mode-and-navigate-or

Answer (score 1):

I would load the image like this:

```
imageObj.onload = function() {
    var cw = $('body').width();
    var ch = Math.floor((cw * this.height) / this.width);

    this.width = cw;
    this.height = ch;

    canvas[0].width = cw;
    canvas[0].height = ch;
    context.drawImage(imageObj,0,0,cw,ch); 
};
```

css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, It Worked :-)

Comment: Antunes, please help me for this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926231/on-canvas-allow-image-area-highlighting-on-zoomin-zoomout-mode-and-navigate-or

Comment: Tomas Antunes , Please help me for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956024/draw-image-area-selectionzoning-on-html-canvas-on-zoom-in-zoom-out-and-regula